# Type error: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' when trying to redirect to different route

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component where I want to redirect to a different route when function is called and response from the server is received. I'm using hooks.

The problem is that I have a TS error `Type error: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.  TS2683`.

In my tsconfig I tried to put `"noImplicitAny": false` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Is there a way to fix it in this situation?

```
export const SignupForm = () => {
    const name:any = handleUserInput('');

    function registerUser(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void {
        event.preventDefault();

        axios.post('/users/register', registerInfo)
            .then(response => {
                this.context.history.push('/some/Path');
            })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="form-holder">
                <form action="POST" className="form" onSubmit={(e) => registerUser(e)}>...</div>
    );
}
```

**EDIT**
  Also getting this error if I try to `console.log(this)` at the top of my component `The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this' which implicitly has type 'any'.  TS7041`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't understand where context coming from..

you can use "withRouter" HOC from 'react-route' module 
and the use props.history.push instead of this.context.history.push